# String in the Struct

Tags: c

I have a problem and I couldn't find any solution about this. In the `example.h` I define the struct by this:

```
#define TOTAL_NUMBER 3

struct{
  float FirstValue[TOTAL_NUMBER];
  float LastValue[TOTAL_NUMBER];

} VALUES;
```

And I want to use in the *example.c* like this.

```
VALUES.FirstValue={1,2,3}
```

But I have an error. How can I use like this in the *example.c* ?

```
VALUES.FirstValue={1,2,3}
```

Comment: Which error do you get ? Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign array as you do for normal variable.

But you can use `memcpy` to copy the compound literals as below.

```
memcpy(VALUES.FirstValue, (float[]){1,2,3}, sizeof VALUES.FirstValue);
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can't.

The general syntax

```
 SomeArrayVariable = {1,2,3};
```

is valid only as initialization - not as assignment.

Example:

```
int arr[3];
arr = {1, 2, 3}; // Error - invalid assignment

int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3}; // Fine - valid initialization
```

Instead you can do:

```
VALUES.FirstValue[0] = 1;
VALUES.FirstValue[1] = 2;
VALUES.FirstValue[2] = 3;
```

or you can do like:

```
struct{
  float FirstValue[TOTAL_NUMBER];
  float LastValue[TOTAL_NUMBER];

} VALUES = {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}};
```

to make it an initialization.

That said.. it's more common to make a typedef'ed struct and then make instances of that type where you need it. This will also allow you to use initialization. Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TOTAL_NUMBER 3

typedef struct{
  float FirstValue[TOTAL_NUMBER];
  float LastValue[TOTAL_NUMBER];    
} values_t;

int main(void) {
    values_t values = {{1,2,3}, {0, 0, 0}};
    printf("%f\n", values.FirstValue[1]);
    printf("%f\n", values.LastValue[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can overwrite previous struct values and set individual members by using *compound literals*:

```
typedef struct{
  float FirstValue[3];
  float LastValue[3];

} VALUES;

int main()
{
  VALUES v;
  v = (VALUES) { .FirstValue = {1,2,3} };
}
```

This is similar to `memset` all zeroes, followed by `memcpy`.

Comment: @CKocar Works just fine. Added a complete code example.